# How to protect authorized_keys file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsa

I have setup key-based-only SSH login (and denied root login) to my Ubuntu server

`ls -l /home/ernest/.ssh` shows this:

`-rw------- 1 ernest ernest 405 Dec 14 09:17 authorized_keys`

Is this means that any process running under `ernest` (my administrative login) can modify `authorized_keys` and аs a result I will lose access to my server?

If yes, is there any practices to protect `authorized_keys`?

Comment: So you're trying to protect that file against... yourself?

Comment: @Mat Well, technically yes. The idea here is that a rogue or malicious processed launched by the user could lock them out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pretty common to simply remove write-access to that file if you're not planning to change it often.

This is also [suggested by the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Securing_the_authorized_keys_file):

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, of course, that write access could be added back in by a malicious script, so you need to set the file and its parent directory to be immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chattr +i ~/.ssh
```